# multiple gradient to sass variable

Tags: sass

I want to add multi-browser based single gradient value to one sass variable. Help me with syntax. I tried below syntax but not getting result. Compiler aborts.

$bg-gradient : -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%), 
-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%),
-o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%),
linear-gradient(to right, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%),

Comment: The Bourbon mixin library has a mixin specifically for this: http://bourbon.io/docs/#linear-gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this as a sass variable; however, it is possible to use a mixin to get the same result:

```
@mixin bggradient() {
    -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%), 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%), 
    -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%),
}
```

Then to call this mixin in your sass code:

```
@include bggradient();
```

Here is more information about mixins: http://sass-lang.com/guide

---

Comment: Thanks for remind me that mixins can be helpful in this.

Comment: I resolved it in following way.

_Sass for Mixin in **mixins-lc.sass** file  :_


`=bggradient()
 background: linear-gradient( to right, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%)
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%)
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%)
 background: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(32,40,0) 0%, rgb(56,72,0) 49%, rgb(84,111,0) 100%)`


_Calling Sass_

'
@import mixins-lc
.bg-grad
 +bggradient
`